# Not able to show underline to text in iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to display some of text in string with under line. it is working fine on all platforms except iOS 8.2

here is my code.

```
 //Terms of use
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedstring= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:TERMSOFUSE attributes:nil];
NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(29, 18);
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
[attributedstring setAttributes:linkAttributes range:linkRange];
self.lbl_termsofuse.attributedText = attributedstring;
```

the strange thing is above code working fine for iOS 8.2 also when I give postion 0 but not for other positions.

Appreciate for help

Answer (score 0):

just call this methode

```
- (void)underlineLabel:(UILabel*)lbl {

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText;
if (!lbl.attributedText) {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lbl.text];
} else {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:lbl.attributedText];
}
long len = [lbl.text length];
if (self.underlineColor) {
     [attributedText addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:self.underlineColor range:NSMakeRange(0,len)];
} else {
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:lbl.textColor range:NSMakeRange(0,len)];
}


[attributedText addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];//Underline color

lbl.attributedText = attributedText;
```

}

Comment: Posted code by me and u both working when gave postion 0 but not for other position